# Cartoon/anime I watched years ago about a teen who had a necklace that could let him control or influence animals/creatures

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was about a teen who had a necklace that could let him control or influence animals/creatures. I think he had a bird he used to scout.

I could be wrong but he may have been part of a tribe and they were trying to get to a new land, somewhere safe.

He had missing memories (maybe) or he was found as a baby with a necklace. It grew and gained more beads which meant more powers.

There was a spirit land.

The main group were three teens: a girl, him and one other boy.

I think most of it was in rocky lands, or at least part; I remember a valley.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it was made? Also, can you describe the appearance of the three teens, particularly their hair colour/style and clothing?

Comment: Also, did the boy control/influence animals already present in the local environment, or was he summoning creatures out of thin air? And did the other two teens have any special powers or skills?

Comment: Also, was this a series or a one-off?

Comment: It was a series as at lest multiple episodes don’t know how many the I think the beads were more like charms and they might have been found or I think they formed/ appear after a spirtalland thing happened when he found stuff out and he might have had a pet or at lest a animal that followed him

Comment: I am not sure when made a lot of the shows that I watch back then I now realise we’re older then I thought I watched it on tv I think it was around same as master waterdrop was on I think that what other was called

Comment: I think they were brown dark tan not sure witch sorry if that sounds offensive but not sure how else to discribe a colored cartoon character.   Not I don’t think the others had powers but they had the skill to easy climb and stuff I think black hair I think hers was in Baird and there clothes were basic main didn’t wear a shirt and just shorts or lonecloth thing girl had a shirt/dress thing that don’t know what called it covered her but moving was easy or it was a two piece set and I have it wrong.     I think he influenced the animals already there and maybe mostly to keep them from attacking